# jQuery synchronization issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a two ajax calls with json.
The first helps me getting the `globalVar` value.
The second takes this value, pass it to an argument in a remote url then returns a result.

```
var globalVar = "";

var firstRemoteUrl = "http://example.com/some/json";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: firstRemoteUrl ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                globalVar = data;
            }
        });


var secondRemoteUrl = "http://example.com/another/json?var = " + globalVar;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: secondRemoteUrl ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

The problem with these kind of calls is that the second ajax call doesn't wait until the first one achieves its call.
So, sometimes, the globalVar is empty. Thus, the second call will not properly end.

I tried with `async` set ti `false` but, as it's indicated in the jquery documentation, the `jsonp` datatype ignore synchronous calls.

Is there a workarround for this issue?

Thanks,

Regards.

Comment: I found another workarround by adding a "wait":
function pausecomp(millis) 
{
 var date = new Date();
 var curDate = null;
 do { curDate = new Date(); } 
 while(curDate-date < millis);
} 
(found here: http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the second call in the callback of the first one. It's a little messy but should get the job done. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://example.com/some/json",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(data) {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://example.com/another/json?var = " + data,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the second ajax call in the success callback function of first ajax call.

```
var firstRemoteUrl = "http://example.com/some/json";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: firstRemoteUrl ,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            globalVar = data;
            secondRemoteUrl = "http://example.com/another/json?var = " + globalVar;
                             $.ajax({
                                     type: "GET",
                                     url: secondRemoteUrl ,
                                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                                      success: function (data) {
                                                  alert(data);
                                                }
                                      });
                            }
          });
```